# PHP - Can't create new Google Calendar event using an API Key

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to insert a new event using only an `API Key` that I created.

The problem is that when I'm just checking available times using FreeBusy, everything works perfectly, but when I try to create and insert a new event, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

In the *Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API* page it is stated that:

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other
>   authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google
>   Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

But I can't manually authorize access to the calendar every time it is asked for.

How can I authorize requests and insert new events without having to manually authorize them?

Comment: If you read the rest of the page in the docs https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth you will see that once a user has authorized your app to access their calendar, it will issue you a token that you can store and user for future calls to the API.

Comment: @lufc Yes, I know that. The problem is that after 1 hour the token expires and I have to manually run my code again through the terminal just so I can get the auth link, give my consent, copy the code, paste it in the terminal and then finally refresh the token.

Comment: Use a refresh token to generate a new token outside the first hour. See here `getRefreshToken()` https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Service Account, if you want to perform server-to-server API requests. Please see https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth.

Generally you'd create a key, and download the JSON file that is provided. You can then call `$client->setAuthConfig($jsonPath);` to set up authentication. It's probably a good idea to keep the private key outside of the web root. Then set the scope using `$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')`, and instantiate the Calendar service using `$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);`. You should now be able to do your stuff.

You may also need to share the calendar with the generated e-mail address that is associated with the Service Account.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably open another question for this, but long story short: I have to create a new service account within the same project, get a new private key and use said private key to authorize the request, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, but it's not working for me, unfortunately. I've downloaded the json, I'm certain the path to my private key is correct, I can read the calendar using FreeBusy but when I try to insert an event, now it throws the error "Not Found".

Comment: Have you shared the calendar with the Service Account's email address?

Comment: Yes, my service account only has reading permissions. I can't give it editing permissions since the option is greyed out. Anyway, shouldn't the API return with another error since my json is valid? I keep getting a 404 error when trying to insert an event.

Comment: Before you've resolved all of the dependencies, I wouldn't count on the API always returning an error that you perceive to be semantically correct. Sometimes semantics are exchanged for security. I'd start by gaining write access before you do any more debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ro Achterberg. It worked now. I couldn't give my service account writing permissions because it didn't have my company email address. Creating a new gmail account just for this did the job.

Comment: Awesome, happy to help.